# PySide segmentation fault on QObject instantiation

Tags: python, python-3.x, segmentation-fault, pyside

I have a class that is a base for my other non-qt classes. This class instantiates QObject class with Signal instance. Unfortunately, sometimes it raises Segmentation Fault error. Here is my code:

```
class PublisherSignal(QObject):
    notify = Signal(list)


class PublisherBase:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PublisherBase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._signal = PublisherSignal()
```

The faulthandler shows, that the segmentation fault is happening on the `PublisherSignal()` class instantiation. It is not always. In most cases it is working fine. No threads are involved. Subclasses of `PublisherBase` are not subclassing `QObject`.
What could be the cause of the segfaults?

Comment: What's wrong with the one I provided? It crashes when instantiating the `PublisherBase` class (which instantiates `PublisherSignal`) which are in the example.

Comment: Your example is not complete, you have only declared 2 classes but you have not used it and you should know that the problem may be caused by how you use it. So it's better that you provide a [mcve] if you want help. :-)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this using python 3.7.1, qt 4.8.7 and pyside 1.2.4. However, since both qt4 and pyside are now totally obsolete, I don't see any point in trying to debug it further. You should switch to pyside2/qt5, and then If the problem still persists, you will need to [report it on the appropriate bug tracker](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python/Reporting_Bugs).

Comment: The problem is that I can't switch to PySide2 since it uses Qt 5. Due to licences, we can't use it. Also, the example is not reproducable in 100%. It mostly works, but sometimes (~1% cases) it explodes with segfault.

Comment: @Djent Well, that is what you get for relying on unsupported legacy software. Issues like this will *never* be fixed now. If you want to diagnose the problem properly, you will have to compile debug builds of at least qt4 and pyside so you can get a full stacktrace. That *might* be enough to reveal what the underlying cause of the issue is (but I wouldn't count on it).

Comment: @Djent I suspect the problem lies in passing complex python types as signal parameters (as opposed to basic types like integers and strings). If so, one possible work-around might be to send the parameters as json strings - or perhaps just try to rewrite your code so there's never any need to send types like `list` and `dict`.

Comment: For a moment I was thinking that changing the type from list to str actually helped, but unfortunately the problem persists. I guess I will need to investigate options to move to PySide2 in this case.

Comment: @Djent It seems highly suspicious that merely emiiting a custom signal with a `str` parameter would cause a segfault. There are an awful lot of pyside programs around that have never had that problem, so you must be doing something different elsewhere in your code. You really should post a complete, minimal example that is known to reproduce the problem. The code currently in your question clearly cannot do that.

Answer (score 4):

First: `Segmentation fault` is a complicated issue for developers. To effectively handle it use [fault handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/faulthandler.html). It is a part of Python v.3.x but you could install it in Python v.2.x using **pip**. But sometimes you'd better use event filter Register – for a widget to track signal events for. Here's an example for mouse (it's just to see how it looks like):

```
# IT IS JUST AN EXAMPLE (NOT A SOLUTION)

def eventFilter(self, source, event):
    if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
        if source == self.txtEditor :
            pos=event.pos()
            cursor=self.txtEditor.cursorForPosition(pos)
            cursor.select(QTextCursor.WordUnderCursor)
            txtClicked=cursor.selectedText()
            self.testCommand(str(txtClicked))
    return QMainWindow.eventFilter(self, source, event)
```

Second: You might use [The Python Debugger](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) module:

```
python -m pdb yourScript.py
```

Third: For threads involved (but you said that no threads are involved).

```
shutdown (exit) can hang or segfault with daemon threads running
```

Comment: I am using faulthandler, and it is telling me that the segmentation fault is caused by the instantiation of the `PublisherSignal` object. No idea why.